# How does maven jetty package a war?

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am running an open source piece of software (https://github.com/att/XACML) and the documentation says to use maven jetty to run the application. This works fine.

However, I am trying to run it without maven as a dependency, so I am thinking of using the generated war and deploying it with jetty. However, this approach gives me errors specific to the war (can not instantiate null etc.) that do not sure up when running maven jetty.

So my question is: how does maven jetty package the war? Is there anything it does at runtime that would make it different than just trying to deploy the war on its own? What is the difference between using maven jetty and using something like jetty runner with the war generated from maven clean install?

Comment: To my understanding the jetty goals in Maven does not create a war but instead sets up a direct deployment to an embedded jetty.  In other words, there is nothing to grab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty does not package a war.

Maven does, and you need ...

1. Your project's `pom.xml` should be declared as `<packaging>war</packaging>`
2. You have a `src/main/webapp` directory.
3. You have maven execute the `package` phase.

When you use something like `mvn jetty:run-war` the first thing that happens is the `package` phase executes, THEN the `jetty:run-war` goal executes.

See: [JettyRunWarMojo.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.20.v20190813/jetty-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/maven/plugin/JettyRunWarMojo.java#L48-L50)

```java
@Mojo(name = "run-war", 
      requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE_PLUS_RUNTIME)
@Execute(phase = LifecyclePhase.PACKAGE)
public class JettyRunWarMojo extends AbstractMojo
```

Jetty is not doing the packaging of war, Maven and it's default `package` phase is (and the behaviors here are determined by the standard maven lifecycle defined by your `<packaging>war</packaging>`)

See: https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging

Comment: Maybe I should have been more specific in my question, but maven jetty (as a command) does package a war and deploy it in one step, and I'm wondering if that does anything differently than just compiling a war by other means.